# How to skip Validation Phase of <af:inputtext>?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have a `<af:selectOneChoice>` with `immediate=true` and `autoSubmit=true`, and a `<af:inputText>` with `rendered=#{bean.someValue}`, `required=true` and `immediate=true`.

When I select `choice 1` from `<af:selectOneChoice>` the `bean.someValue` is false, therefore `<af:inputText>` is not rendered. And when I select `choice 2` from `<af:selectOneChoice>` the `bean.someValue` is true, therefore `<af:inputText>` is rendered.

**Test Case:** Initially, `choice 1` is selected in `<af:selectOneChoice>`, therefore `<af:inputText>` is not rendered. As I select `choice 2` in `<af:selectOneChoice>`, `<af:inputText>` is rendered and it becomes visible. When I again select `choice 1` in `<af:selectOneChoice>`, the page throws and error `Enter a value`, but the value of  `<af:selectOneChoice>` changes to `choice 1`.

In this case, I want that the value of `<af:selectOneChoice>` should revert back to `choice 2`.

How to do this?

Comment: Throw in some code (at least jsf). There can be many pitfals in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your test case, so you're saying when the inputText is empty, you change the selectOneChoice to choice 1, and since your inputText "required" attribute is set to true, so ADF throws an visual error remind you to "enter a value", till now everything is what you expected, right? But although the error msg pops out, the selectOneChoice still got to change to choice 1, this is the problem right?

I guess to prevent the selectOneChoice value to change to choice 1 in the error case, you can add some verification code in the valueChangeListener of the selectOneChoice component from the back bean, to decide whether the value should be changed.